# jinja2 syntax highlighting definitions for Panic's Coda 2?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, jinja2, coda

Question says it all. Anyone know of a syntax highlighter for jinja2 in Coda2? The Python modes and HTML modes kinda sorta work... and yet... not really.

Comment: Dang, this would be really helpful- too bad it doesn't exist!